# How to remove the number and seconds text from this codepen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, plugins

I am simply trying to put custom text in the center of this countdown circle but I can't figure out how to replace the number and text currently in the center.

Codepen link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqjdRg

Example Code:

```
<div class="progress-pie-chart" data-start-time="30" data-percent="30">
  <div class="ppc-progress">
    <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ppc-percents">
    <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
      <span>Changing this does nothing</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought if I change the span text it would work but no dice :(

Comment: its done by javascript, where it says `$('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+' sec');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your change in line number 40.

```
$('.ppc-percents span').html('Your text');
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/rmrinmoy/pen/GZdvXv)**

Answer (score 0):

The trick lies in line no. 40 of JS : `$('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+' sec');`.
Using this line, the span inside  is set with the text **'n' seconds remaining**. If you want to remove that text, just remove line 40 in JS.